# Don't show .getDisplayMedia() screen select + start pop-up

Tags: javascript, getusermedia, get-display-media

Currently, I'm working on a WebRTC screen sharing proof of concept.

```js
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
    video: {
        cursor: "always"
    },
    audio: false
});
```

[image]

I'm looking for a solution for one thing.
In my application, a user can ask another user to start sharing his screen. When doing so, the user gets a pop-up window to select the screen he wants to share and is giving his permission to start sharing the screen.

Is there an option to auto select, for example screen 1 and start sharing this without asking the user for permission? Any solution to this problem can (probably) be implemented because we manage the laptops ourselves.

I tried to Google this “problem” but was not able to find any solutions to it.
But maybe someone here has become very creative and found a solution?